# Drawing a Graph in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to draw a graph of the function

```
 h(t)  =  200 - (1/2)9.8t^2 + 8t
```

but I keep receiving unexpected symbol errors when I do:

```
curve(200 - (1/2)*(9.8)t^2 + 8*t)
```

Any idea how to graph it correctly, and why I received the errors?

Comment: What are the errors you have received? It will also be helpful if you can provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) w/ some sample data & what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your command:

1. `curve` expects the variable to be named `x`, not `t`.
2. The multiplication sign `*` is missing between `(9.8)` and `x`.

Try

```
curve(200 - (1/2)*(9.8)*x^2 + 8*x)
```

Giving

[image]